# Como instalar Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-2.7

Sou novo com Ubuntu e estou aprendendo Python.

Eu tenho instalado no meu pc o Pyhton 2.7.12 e gostaria de saber como eu faço para atualizar para a versão 3.

Estou fazendo um curso onde preciso fazer utilizar uma lib.

```
import urllib.request
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro:

```
import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Olhando na internet vi alguns comentários dizendo que para isso funcionar precisava rodar o arquivo com o python 3 instalado.

Gostaria saber como instalar o python 3 para solucionar este erro.

Comment: Utilize Eclipse é melhor pratica para desenvolver, e segue o site https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Pydev-Preparando-o-Eclipse-para-o-Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Ubuntu uma das formas para instalar qualquer pacote é utilizar o apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install <nome do pacote>
```

Caso você não saiba o nome do pacote utiliza:

```
apt-cache search <nome do pacote>
```

No caso do python3 ficaria:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Para checar a instalação:

```
 python3 --version
```

Para usar o python3:

```
python3 arquivo.py
```

Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Só lembrar também de NÂO TENTAR DESINSTALAR o Python 2 para instalar o Python 3 no Ubuntu (nem depois de instalar) - Python2 e 3 podem existir lado a lado. Desisntalar o Python2 vai quebrar o seu sistema, talvez de forma irremediável.